# Moving the header in django-admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

i am new to django, and i put the image in my admin header, but the name is blocking it, so i was wondering how to move the name a bit to the middle of the page. Simply adding the spaces in front of the name doesnt work, because for some reason it ignores all the extra spaces.

```
{% block extrastyle %}
<style type='text/css'>
    #header {
        background-color: #0c407a;      
    }   

    #branding {
        height:94px;
        background-color: #0c407a;
        background: white url('/static/logo2.jpg') no-repeat ;
    }

</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="myid"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ _('       MyName') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can try with adding some CSS code:

```
#myid{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```